# Moving position in quicklaunch SPNavigationNodeCollection

Tags: quick-launch

This is my code to reorder the QuickLaunch Navigation Nodes Position.
I am using the SharePoint 2013.

```
    public void 2013NodeOrders(string siteUrl, string quickLaunch)
            { 
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
                        {
                            using (var localWeb = new SPSite(siteUrl).OpenWeb())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    var ql = localWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
                                     for (int j = 0; j < nodeNames.Count; j++)
                                                 {
                                                 var postionInTarget = FindPositionInTarget(nodeNames[j], localWeb);
                                                  if (postionInTarget == -1) continue;//means we didnt find that for some reason
                                                     MoveNodeToPosition(j, postionInTarget, localWeb);
                                                     localWeb.Update();
                                                 }
                                                localWeb.Update();

                                }                                   }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                   Console.WriteLine("Error Occoured ", ex);
                                    throw ex;
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }





    private void MoveNodeToPosition(int positionToMoveTo, int postionInTarget, SPWeb localWeb)
              {

                 var ql = localWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
                 if (positionToMoveTo == postionInTarget) return;
                 if (positionToMoveTo == 0)
                 {
                      localWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                      ql[postionInTarget].MoveToFirst(ql);
                         localWeb.Update();
                        return;
                 }            
                    if (positionToMoveTo < ql.Count)
                    {
                    //positionToMoveTo = positionToMoveTo - ql.Count;
                    localWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                     ql[postionInTarget].Move(ql, ql[positionToMoveTo - 1]); 
                     localWeb.Update();
                 }
             }


        private int FindPositionInTarget(string p, SPWeb localWeb)
               {

                 localWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
               var ql = localWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
                  int count = ql.Count;
                 try
                 {
                       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                         {
                         if (ql[i].Title == p)
                          {
                               localWeb.Update();
                                 return i;
                               }
                         }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                      Logging.LogWriteLine("Find PositionInTarget method failed with exception ", ex);
                    }
                 return -1;
            }
```

Error Message :

Cannot complete this action.
        Please try again.0x80004005 in the line  "if (ql[i].Title == p) return i;" and also the exception message while moving the node position "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values" in the lineql[postionInTarget].Move(ql, ql[positionToMoveTo - 1]);